# Custom URI schema that returns data

Tags: android, uri, android-manifest, android-service

Yes, I know that defining custom URI schemata is a bad idea in general. Still, let me ask.

If you define a custom schema via a BROWSABLE intent-filter, is there a way to make that schema return data back to the browser? Not necessarily from activity (although that'd be nice); maybe a service would do?

Tried doing that by calling setResult() in a BROWSABLE activity, passing back an Intent with a data URI in it. Did not work.